# display custom attribute inside text field

Tags: attributes, html

We are using following code to display Price **inside TextField**

```
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>
```

[image]

We are using following code to display a custom attribute COD.

I want to know what code we need to use for displaying COD **inside textfield**

```
 <?php  
    $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');
    if ($attribute) {
    echo $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products);
    }
    ?>
```

i am getting the COD value , i want to display inside text field as like price

[image]

Comment: try this <?php echo $attribute; ?> in  textbox value. I hope this what you are asking

Comment: use this value = "<?php echo $products->getCodAvailable(); ?>".Do you want to show both price and COD?

Comment: @Kothari i am getting cod, i updated the question , check images.

Comment: @mujas pleasse check updated  question.

Comment: follow @Akhilesh Answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');?>
<?php if ($attribute): ?>
     <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products);; ?>" style = ""/>
<?php else :?>
    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "price[]" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = ""/>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?> ', expecting ':' in can you please check

Comment: updated ans check now

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $product->getAttributeText('cod_available'); ?>" />
```

Edit

```
<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');?>
    <?php if($attribute):?>
        <?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>
        <input type = "text" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value; ?>" />
    <?php endif; ?>
```

It might be case you will not get this attribute value for all the products.

Comment: its not working,   i want to inform i am not displaying this in product view page

Comment: Can you show your complete code?

Comment: please search  text  "COD start"  here : http://pastebin.com/3avm02r4

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: sorry boss, its working, i missed the code.... + 1  from me

Answer (score 1):

ou can just config it in attribute edit page

Used in Product Listing -> Yes

and use

```
$attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products);

<input type = "text" id = "attr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" name= "" value = "<?php echo $attribute_value ?>" style = ""/>
```

**I hope this will help you.**

Comment: i am getting Fatal error: Call to a member function getFrontend() on a non-object in

Comment: Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'attribute_code', $storeId);

try this

Comment: you can also use

$product->getResource()->getAttribute($attribute_code)
        ->getFrontend()->getValue($product)